# sql group by and get combinations?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Sample data:**

```
Serial | Name
-------------------------
     1 |  aaaa
     1 |  bbbb
     1 |  cccc
     2 |  aaaa
     3 |  bbbb
     3 |  aaaa
     3 |  cccc
     4 |  bbbb
     4 |  cccc
```

if I group it by `serial` I have 4 groups.

```
Serial | record count in group |  name in group |
----------------------------------------
    1  |                    3  | aaaa,bbbb,cccc |
    2  |                    1  |           aaaa |
    3  |                    3  | aaaa,bbbb,cccc |
    4  |                    2  |      bbbb,cccc |
```

and group by `record count in group`

```
repeat count | name in record count | repeat repeat count |
----------------------------------------------------------|
           1 |                 aaaa |                   1 |
           2 |            bbbb,cccc |                   1 |
           3 |       aaaa,bbbb,cccc |                   2 |
```

after all group data, I want this: (last result that my expected)

How can I achieve following?

```
| Name | record count in group | Available Count |
|------------------------------------------------|
| aaaa |                     3 |               2 | (there are 2 aaaa in 3 combinations)
|------------------------------------------------| 
| aaaa |                     1 |               1 | (there is 1 aaaa in  1 combination)
|------------------------------------------------|
| bbbb |                     3 |               2 | (there is 2 bbb in  3 combinations)
|------------------------------------------------|
| bbbb |                     2 |               1 | ...
|------------------------------------------------|
| cccc |                     3 |               2 |
|------------------------------------------------|
| cccc |                     2 |               1 |
|------------------------------------------------|
```

I tried some thing like following: **[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d12ab/4)**

```
SELECT Serial, COUNT(Serial) GroupCount, Name = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Name
       FROM your_table b 
       WHERE b.Serial = a.Serial 
       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM your_table a
GROUP BY Serial
```

But I should write a search query to find my expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about you're actual requirements, but this might be what you want:

```
SELECT Name, cnt, COUNT(*)
FROM
 (
   SELECT Serial, Name,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Serial) as cnt 
   FROM your_table
 ) a
GROUP BY Name, cnt
```

Get the count of rows per Serial as a Windowed Count and then group by it: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d12ab/20/0)